# How to secure healtchecks in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am including the following nuget package: `AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks` with the HealthChecks.UI part to graphically display the status of the configured services.

Is there anything already implemented to add security to it, so that cannot be displayed without security?

Answer (score 10):

Health checks use the authentication and authorization mechanisms used for endpoint routing. The [Health Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1) guide explains how to [use authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#require-authorization) with `RequiresAuthorization`, eg :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health").RequireAuthorization();
});
```

The default policy requires authentication only. The [Authorization for specific endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authorization-for-specific-endpoints) section shows how to create custom authorization policies, and specify them by name, or by passing the policy name.

The *last* example, is probably more interesting :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints
        .MapHealthChecks("/healthz")
        .RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute(){ Roles = "admin", });
});
```

The [AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) attribute implements [IAuthorizeData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizedata?view=aspnetcore-3.1), the interface implemented by all authorization policies.