# Is it possible to protect HealthCheck endpoints other than Authorization in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware, health-check

The case I'm trying to handle is protecting the health endpoint generated by using `IEndpointRouteBuilder.MapHealthChecks` not via authorization, but by some other mechanism.

My first thought was to add an `IActionFilter`, but I don't see how that's possible. I tried adding the attribute as metadata with a call to `IEndpointConventionBuilder.WithMetadata` but it seems like unless it's implemented to make use of those attributes, it'll just ignore them.

As such, my best solution right now was to do the following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health").Add(endpointBuilder =>
    {
        RequestDelegate next = endpointBuilder.RequestDelegate!;
        endpointBuilder.RequestDelegate = async context =>
        {
            bool success = true;
            
            // Do your custom logic here.

            if (success)
            {
                await next();
            }
            else
            {
                // Do I need to set some headers here as well?
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
            }
            
        };
    });

    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Using the above `Add` method, I'm able to chain my logic like that, but it feels hacky. Is there really no other alternative to adding filters to the generated `/health` endpoint above?

The reason I don't want to use a policy, is because the application doesn't even have authorization/authentication enabled. In order to import my logic into a policy, I'd have to register an authentication scheme, which seems dirty, granted I won't even be using it.

Comment: I'm afraid not,you need to use [Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166270/how-to-secure-healtchecks-in-asp-net-core).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach you're taking looks reasonable. In .NET 7 you'll be able to add filters that can run before endpoints like this. We'd generally recommend integrating with the auth system but I can understand just wanting to write a function that returns a bool :).

Comment: Could you update your answer with how one would be able to integrate this into .NET 7 once the functionality is in preview? Thank you for everything you do for the ASP.NET Core community davidfowl! :)